# Problem on Binomial Distribution

Tags: probability

X and Y are contesting in an election. 72% of the population supports X. The rest support B. However, an X-supporter goes to cast his vote with 0.5 probability. A Y-supporter goes to cast his vote with 0.32 probability.
What is the probability of X's win?

My attempt:

This can be modelled as a problem of two coins X (p=0.5),Y(p=0.32) being tossed 72 and 28 times repeatedly. The #successes form a binomial distribution.

Then we calculate the probability that A *loses*:

If x, y are the binomial PDFs of X,Y:

$$P_\text{loss}=x(27)\cdot  y(28) + x(26) \cdot [y(27) + y(28)] + x(25) \cdot [y(26) + y(27) + y(28)] + \cdots$$

Then we find $P_\text{win}=1-P_\text{loss}$

But all this summing seems too much work. Is there some logic I'm failing to see?

Answer (score 0):

Your method seems to be the most straightforward approach, and it does seem like way too much summation to do by hand.  Having said that, here's my go at writing down a more compact form of the sum using their PDFs.  Starting with the PDFs:
$$p_x(x)={72 \choose x}0.5^{72}$$ $$p_y(y)={28\choose y}(0.32)^y(0.68)^{28-y}$$Where X and Y are independent random variables representing the number of votes cast for each candidate.  Then, keeping in mind that $P(X \gt Y)=1-P(X \le Y)$:
$$P(X \le Y)=\sum_{k=0}^{28}P(X=k)P(Y\ge k)$$
$$P(X \le Y)=\sum_{k=0}^{28} \left(p_x(k)*\sum_{j=k}^{28}p_y(j)\right) $$
$$P(X \le Y)=\sum_{k=0}^{28}\sum_{j=k}^{28}p_x(k)p_y(j)$$
$$P(X \gt Y)=1-\sum_{k=0}^{28}\sum_{j=k}^{28}p_x(k)p_y(j)$$
So now you can at least express the answer in terms of the PDFs a bit more succinctly.  Still not a very satisfying response, I know.  Running a quick program I wrote on a TI-83 I have handy finds that $$P(X \le Y)=2.599810741\times10^{-8}$$ So that $$P(X \gt Y)=0.999999974$$Assuming my TI programming skills are still up to snuff (which they may very well not be).

Comment: Would using the Normal approximation help?  $X\sim \mathcal{B}(n, p) \approx X\sim \mathcal{N}(np, np(1-p))$  Then rather than summing you'd be performing an integration.  Since we don't actually know what $n$ is you're already approximating by taking a representative sample of $100$.

Comment: You're absolutely right about it being an approximation due to the representative sample, I didn't read the question carefully enough and got it in my head that there were 100 people.  I'll take the word 'exact' out of my first sentence up there.  I did play with the normal approximation for a few minutes before posting this, but it didn't seem like it was heading toward something that was any more realistic to compute by hand.  I'll take another look, though.